# Unity3d. Convex collider restrictions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physx

I want to predicate that I cannot set collider to convex.

I already found some restrictions:
- trigs must be between 3 and 254.

But there still some cases that I can not handle:

```
Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[] {
new Vector3(-0.1f, -100f, 0f),
new Vector3( 0.1f, -100f, 0f),
new Vector3(  0f,  100f, 0f),
new Vector3(  0f,  0f, 0.1f),
};

int[] tris = new int[] {
0, 1, 2,
0, 1, 3,
1, 2, 3,
2, 0, 3,
};
```

returns:

> Unhandled log message: [Error] [Physics.PhysX]
>   ConvexHullBuilder::CreateTrianglesFromPolygons: convex hull has a
>   polygon with less than 3 vertices!
>   UnityEngine.MeshCollider:set_convex(Boolean) BzKovSoft.ObjectSlicer.ObjectSlicer.MyTests:Test() (at
>   Assets/BzKovSoft/ObjectSlicer/Editor/MyTests.cs:43)
>   System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke(Object, Object[])
>   NUnit.Framework.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass9_0:b__0()
>   UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()

Could you advice maybe a reference to all this rules for convex collider?